# почему срабатывает цикл While (!false) в данном случае

Tags: java, циклы

Почему срабатывает цикл While в данное случае?

Переменную isSorted инициировали значением false. Условие для срабатывания цикла - true (!isSorted). Почему цикл срабатывает? Переменная ведь false.

Очень хочу понять.

```
public static int[] bubbleSort(int[] nums) {

    boolean isSorted = false;

    while (!isSorted) {       // !isSorted = !false = true

        isSorted = true;

        for (int i = 1; i < nums.length; i++) {

            if (nums[i - 1] > nums[i]) {
                int temp = nums[i];
                nums[i] = nums[i - 1];
                nums[i - 1] = temp;
                isSorted = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return nums;
}
```

Comment: Циклу все равно какие переменные в условии? Если все выражение в скобках дает результат - true, значит будет работать. Правильно я понимаю? П.С. спасибо за терпение. Для меня это очень важно.

Comment: Цикл "смотрит" только на конечный результат логического выражения (true или false), а какие там переменные и какие у них исходные значения - без разницы.

Comment: Спасибо! Разобрался.

Answer (score 3):

#### Для начала посмотрим, что будет без оператора отрицания (без `!`)

Взгляните на это условие:

```
if(isSorted){
    System.out.println("Блок if выполнился!");
}
```

Если мы дадим значение `true` переменной `isSorted`, то блок `if` выполнится и в консоли увидим:

```
Блок if выполнился!
```

Если же значение переменной будет `false`, то блок `if` не сработает и консоль останется пустой.

Из этого можно сделать вывод, что:

```
if(isSorted){ //Тоже самое, что и if(isSorted == true)
     //......
}
```

#### Теперь ваша запись

По скольку `!` - это оператор отрицания, то:

```
if(!isSorted){ //Тоже самое, что и if(isSorted == false)
    //....
}
```

В вашем случае у вас переменная `isSorted` имеет значение `false`. Вы говорите циклу `!isSorted` ("выполнись, если `isSorted` имеет значение `false`"),  вот поэтому цикл выполняется.

Comment: Спасибо за детальный ответ!